# Accessing exit codes from a c program

Tags: c, shell, exit-code

I have tried to find solution all over the internate, but forums keep saying it is impossible, so here I a with my question. How does a shell (any shell like bash) keep track of `exit codes`. Is it by tracking their child process? (if so how could I go about implementing such a thing in a program where I am creating and  killing many children processes) Or Is there a global variable that is equivalent to `$?` that I can access in `c`? Or do they store it in a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of executing grep on a path that doesn't exist and getting the return code in the parent:

## code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    pid_t childPid;
    switch(childPid = fork()) {
    case -1:
        fprintf(stderr, "Error forking");
        return 1;
    case 0:
        printf("CHILD: my pid is: %d\n", getpid());
        int ret = execlp(argv[1], argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], (char *) NULL);
        if (ret == -1) {
            printf("CHILD: execv returned: %d\n", errno);
            return errno;
        }
        break;
    default:
        printf("I am the parent with a child: %d\n", childPid);
        int childRet;
        wait(&childRet);
        printf("PARENT, child returned: %d\n", childRet >> 8);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## Execution:

```
# Example of Failure execution:

[ttucker@zim c]$ cc -o stackoverflow so.c && ./stackoverflow grep test /does/not/exists
I am the parent with a child: 166781
CHILD: my pid is: 166781
grep: /does/not/exists: No such file or directory
PARENT, child returned: 2

# Example of a successful execution:

[ttucker@zim c]$ cc -o stackoverflow so.c && ./stackoverflow echo foo bar
I am the parent with a child: 166809
CHILD: my pid is: 166809
foo bar
PARENT, child returned: 0
```

Comment: ok, so from your answer I am assuming that the shell also knows what to do when you do `echo "$?"`, by keeing track of the exit status of each command in each child.

Comment: Yes, I believe that this the case. I think that in Linux, and likely other operating systems, when you create a process you must fork the current process and exec, as shown. I think that Bash (and this is oversimplified) is just a process that just loops and waits for user inputs, then fork()s and exec()s, while keeping track of a bunch of different things, like return code.

Answer (score 1):

'wait' or 'waitpid'.

With that, you can keep track of child processes and how they were terminated.

You can check the 'wstatus' with the macro 'WEXITSTATUS', which is the return value of the 'main' function (if terminated with 'exit').

Comment: And `WIFEXITED()` to see if it exited normally or ended via some other means (`WIFSIGNALED()` for if it died because of a signal)